# Alternative to memory mapping in Erlang? How does CouchDB do it?

Tags: memory, erlang, mapping, couchdb

I'm interested in porting my database engine from Java to Erlang.

Currently, the Java implementation depends on memory mapping for efficiency. For memory mapping in Erlang, the only thing I've found so far is [emmap](https://github.com/krestenkrab/emmap).

As far as I know, CouchDB does not depend on memory mapping. How does it keep up with efficiency? Does it store as much in memory as possible and flush it to disk as necessary?

Comment: To my knowledge, CouchDB does very little in memory, but it's file format is append-only, so that keeps the file operations generally fast.

Comment: As an alternative, consider building it as a NIF (C or C++). The Erlang NIF API provides synchronization functions for shared resource access, so you could develop the underlying structure in C/C++ and access it from erlang processes. I replicated some of the functionality of ets (erlang term storage) as a NIF for fun; perhaps you could do something similar? http://github.com/fauxsoup/neural

Comment: An interesting note for you ... the guy that wrote CouchDB (Damien Katz) is now re-writing Couchbase - or at least parts of it - in C instead of Erlang. An interesting read: http://damienkatz.net/2013/01/the_unreasonable_effectiveness_of_c.html

Comment: You could always take a peek at the [source](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/tree/master/src). :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a LSM btree, as in

https://github.com/krestenkrab/hanoidb